# How to resolve Connection factory returned null from createConnection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to connect to an oracle database and map the result to a POJO. However I am getting the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection factory returned null from createConnection
```

I have had other spring projects and never encountered this issue so have no idea how to resolve it. I have included my config and class below.

**Servlet xml Snippet**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mnp.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${mnp.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mnp.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mnp.password}" />
</bean>
```

**DAO Implementation**

```
package cdjh.ops.mnpui.daos;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PacEntry;
import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PortEntry;
import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PortRecord;

@Repository
public class QueryDAO extends JdbcTemplate implements IQueryDAO{
    @Resource BasicDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public PortRecord findPortRecord(String msisdn, String pac){
        String sql = "select * from tbl_entry where msisdn = ? and pac_code = ?";
        PortRecord portRecord = queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{msisdn, pac}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<PortRecord>(PortRecord.class));
        return portRecord;
    }

    public void setDataSource(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection factory returned null from createConnection
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:584)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:729)
    cdjh.ops.mnpui.daos.QueryDAO.findPortRecord(QueryDAO.java:41)
    cdjh.ops.mnpui.services.QueryService.findPortRecord(QueryService.java:33)
    cdjh.ops.mnpui.controllers.QueryController.showPortRecord(QueryController.java:58)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested this against a mysql db i built and it works ok, just doesnt seem to work against oracle. The only thing that is changing is the jdbc.properties file.

mysql

```
mnp.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mnp.url=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/mnpui
mnp.username=XXX
mnp.password=XXX
```

Oracle

```
mnp.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
mnp.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:mnpui@172.31.125.37:1523
mnp.username=XXX
mnp.password=XXX
```

do i need to do something different with oracle to make it work?

Comment: Did you supply the Oracle JDBC driver JAR as well?

Comment: Yeah i added the classes12 jar file which i have taken from the oracle installation on the database server. I have both classes12 and connectorj on the class path so i can test against mysql db before releasing war to production server which uses oracle.

Comment: The `classes12` driver is *really* old. Try grabbing a more recent JDBC driver from Oracle's website (e.g. `ojdbc6.jar`) and see if that improves things.

Comment: @skaffman thanks, I have logged off for tonight in frustration so will try this tomorrow with a fresh set of eyes

Comment: @skaffman I replaced classes12 with ojdbc6 and it has resolved the issue. Would you like to post this recommendation as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: OK, reposted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposting original comment as an answer, since it seems to have fixed the issue).

The `classes12.zip` JDBC driver that you're using to connect to Oracle is very old, and was intended for Java 1.2 clients. It's possible that either Spring or Commons DBCP relies on a more modern JDBC version to work, so you should use the more modern `odbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar` (for Java 6 and 7, respectively, although that association is somewhat loose and they're largely interchangeable) instead.

Comment: @sksffmsn thanks, i have built using jav 1.6 and ojdbc6 and all is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't extend `JdbcTemplate` encapsulate it in your dao
2. Why are you injecting a datasource that is never passed to the `JdbcTemplate`?
3. You should be programming against a `DataSource` not a `BasicDataSource`.

```
package cdjh.ops.mnpui.daos;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PacEntry;
import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PortEntry;
import cdjh.ops.mnpui.pojos.PortRecord;

@Repository
public class QueryDAO implements IQueryDAO{

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public QueryDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public PortRecord findPortRecord(String msisdn, String pac){
        String sql = "select * from tbl_entry where msisdn = ? and pac_code = ?";
        PortRecord portRecord = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{msisdn, pac}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(PortRecord.class));
        return portRecord;
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you are actually using the datasource configured in the spring configuration. There is too little information in your post and your initial dao to polutedto be sure of that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I have tided up as you suggested but still run into the illegalStateException

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong with your driver. Judging from the updates/comments you are using classes12 jar file which is really really old it was meant for java 1.2/1.3. You want to go to the Oracle website and download the most recent version of the driver.